# Url parameters of Gmail - open a email with a determined subject

Tags: parameters, gmail

I saw that there's a question about Gmail parameters for "mail to", but I didnt found a answer for this my doubt.

First I need a explain becouse  I need this.

I work with digital mkt and I have a optin page for capture  lead email. After this page, I have a second page with guiding the lead until to email plataform - Gmail, Outlook and so on... for comfirm your email, ok?

So, I want to create a button with a Gmail URL with follow instruction:

Open Gmail end find a specific subject.

I tryed this parameter:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?subject:livro%digital

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?subject=livro%digital

But none of these parameters above worked.

Someone could help me pls.

Thank in advance for help!

Marcos

Comment: Hello everyone ... I found these parameters ...

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/Cadastro+Sorteio+Livro+de+Activities+Plays+label%3Aall

This parameter finds the email but does not open it. If anyone has an idea of ​​how to open the email, it will be really cool.